# Pythonic way of aggregating but without grouping

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate

I have a `df` as follows, where I wish to find of `Sum of orders` and `Number of unique order sizes`, but I don't want to compress the `df`:

```
list_of_lists = [['11','Berlin',2],['11','Berlin',2],['11','Berlin',3],
                 ['22','Munich',1],['22','Munich',1]]

df = pd.DataFrame(list_of_lists, columns=['ID', 'City', 'Order Size'])

    ID  City    Order Size
0   11  Berlin  2
1   11  Berlin  2
2   11  Berlin  3
3   22  Munich  4
4   22  Munich  4
```

I want output be:

```
    ID  City    Order Size   Sum of orders  Number of unique order sizes
0   11  Berlin  2            7              2
0   11  Berlin  2            7              2
0   11  Berlin  3            7              2
3   22  Munich  4            8              1
4   22  Munich  4            8              1
```

I could have easily used `.groupby(['ID','City'])` but that would reduce my `df` to an aggregated `df` of two rows, where I could have done the `left-join` to the original `df`. I want a simpler approach, a pythonic approach.

Comment: I would use groupby and join the result into the original dataframe.

Comment: I have done that using `left join`, but that's not something I want. I am looking for more pythonic solution.